# Where is the review button?

Tags: support

I can access review through URL directly, but cannot see any links which brings me to that part of the site. Am I blind or has it maybe got lost in the new design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be surprised.  There's a lot of areas on the site that are (or, at least, used to be) like that.  However, this isn't one of them anymore.  The "review" link should be between your badge count and the "chat" link, in the top bar of the site.  Here's a shot (box and arrow added) from my screen, on Meta in Firefox 5.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For anon users at the top of the page:

> log in blog careers chat meta about faq

For registered users with >= 200 rep at the top of the page

> Username 500  review  chat meta about faq

For registered users with >= 10k rep at the top of the page:

> Username 10,000  tools  chat  meta  faq